# Solidity logic implementation using block.timestamp

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, remix

i'm trying to implement some logic involving block.timestamps and i keep getting this weird transaction revert:

The first time i call the function doLogic(), the transaction gets reverted. The second time i call it, it works (and after that it always works). I guess it has to do with the updated blocktime because the first call of doLogic() gets reverted but still updates the value of block.timestamp? maybe some of you already had issues with this and can help me!

(now is equivalent to block.timestamp)

[image]

```
pragma solidity 0.6.0;


contract TestStamps {

    uint256 time;
    bool test;

    constructor() public {
        time = now;
    }

    function getTime() public view returns (uint256) {
        return time;
    }

    function updateBlock() public  {
        time = now;
    }

    function doLogic() public {
        if (now > time) {
            test = true;
        } else {
            test = false;
        }
    }

    function getTestBool () public view returns (bool) {
        return test;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a Remix issue, and nothing to do with your code.

Comment: thats what i thought, because when i call the function from my javscript backend via web3 there is no error thrown..